# Correct way of using removeObserver in Master/Detail application

Tags: ios, objective-c, master-detail

In a master-detail application, I have the following layout;

**Master**
Let's assume we have a UITableView here

**Detail**
Shows more information about a item from the Master. We setup a observer in NSNotificationCenter here

**DetailModal**
Shows something, is shown from Detail

Where is the correct way of calling `removeObserver` if I still want to receive notifications when Detail or DetailModal is shown but remove it when we go back to Master?

The way I see it, I would set a flag to not remove the observer when showing the DetailModal and check for that flag in `viewWillDissapear`. Is this a good approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not dealloc - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6469209/objective-c-where-to-remove-observer-for-nsnotification) for a discussion.

It's best to do it in ViewWillDisappear. I usually have a boolean "isObserving" flag that is set when observing starts and then checked when ViewWillDisappear is called.

eta- best practice suggests it should actually be done in both, but the dealloc is only a backstop.

eta#2: With ARC, dealloc is only called when the reference count falls to zero. If it's observing, a reference still exists and so dealloc never gets called.

Comment: Sounds like my idea of a flag and check in viewWillDisappear would be the way then.

Comment: the selected answer in the link you pasted is actually saying to use dealloc

Comment: The discussion is spread out 
over that question, this is perhaps a better link: http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/311831-arc-and-dealloc.html

Answer (score 0):

I usually call `removeObserver` on the `- (void)dealloc` method of my subview / subview controller. After popping the `DetailModal` it should be released.