# Is removing observer obligatory (necessary)?

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter

There is an observer that I need it in all of app life cycle, shall I ever remove it?
I think `GC` will remove it after app is closed, am I right?
If yes, then when shall I remove it? in `deinit`?

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15941336/4539192). This is provided you are giving iOS 8 support, iOS 9 onwards it is no longer necessary, you can read more [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/Foundation/RN-Foundation/index.html#10_11NotificationCenter).

Comment: Great, please send this as an answer so I accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are providing support to iOS 8 and before. You will have to remove the observer inside `dealloc` or `viewWillDisappear`. A more detailed answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15941336/4539192).

If you are providing support from iOS 9 onwards, it is no longer necessary to manually remove the observer. From apple docs:

> In OS X 10.11 and iOS 9.0 NSNotificationCenter and
>   NSDistributedNotificationCenter will no longer send notifications to
>   registered observers that may be deallocated. If the observer is able
>   to be stored as a zeroing-weak reference the underlying storage will
>   store the observer as a zeroing weak reference, alternatively if the
>   object cannot be stored weakly (i.e. it has a custom retain/release
>   mechanism that would prevent the runtime from being able to store the
>   object weakly) it will store the object as a non-weak zeroing
>   reference. This means that observers are not required to un-register
>   in their deallocation method.

A more detailed explanation can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/Foundation/RN-Foundation/index.html#10_11NotificationCenter).

**Note:** However be careful when using block-based notifications as mentioned in the doc linked above.