# Terminating app due to uncaught exception, reason: 'ERROR: UIScrollView does not support multiple observers implementing

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview

'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'ERROR: UIScrollView does not support multiple observers implementing _scrollViewWillEndDraggingWithVelocity:targetContentOffset:'

I checked all related questions but not got exactly problem is where.

I have a custom Tab bar and by defaults first is selected and when we select the second tab and come back on first. I got the app to crash.

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using UINavigationController with Title in UINavigationBar ?

Comment: Yes @Mrunal I'm using.

Comment: Try using this `self.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you manually adding KVO to your code?

If so, you need to add

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self]
```

in your view controllers `- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated` method.

Also, it seems like you are observing a selector that is already observed by the scroll view internally, do not subscribe to selectors that are used internally by UIKit

see [removing observers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6469209/objective-c-where-to-remove-observer-for-nsnotification)

Comment: No, I didn't add any KVO or Local Notification.

Answer (score 0):

I just simply replace code at the time of push and my problem solved.

```
 self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
    let controller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: MainStoryBoard.ViewControllerIdentifiers.tabbarViewController) as! TabBarViewController
    controller.selectedIndex = 0
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
```

instead below code

```
 let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let controller = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: MainStoryBoard.ViewControllerIdentifiers.tabbarViewController) as! TabBarViewController
    // Feature Tab
    controller.selectedIndex = 0
    let appdelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    appdelegate.window?.rootViewController = controller
    appdelegate.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```