# How can I play the same sound again once it has finished playing using the AVAudioPlayer framework?

Tags: objective-c, ios, avaudioplayer

I want my sound file to be played three times subsequently. However, it is only played once.
I guess when the `[crashSound play]` is called for a second time the sound hasn't finished being played so any subsequent calls are lost. How can I fix that. i.e. How can I make it so that the same file is played again once it has finished its current play?

```
@interface Game()
{
    // code...

    AVAudioPlayer *crashSound;

    // code...
}
@end

@implementation Game

- (id) init 
{ 
    // code...

    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSURL *crashSoundFile = [bundle URLForResource: @"crashSound" withExtension: @"wav"];
    crashSound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:crashSoundFile error:NULL];

    // code...
}
-(void) play // this is my "main" method that will be called once the playButton is pressed
{
   [crashSound play];[crashSound play];[crashSound play];

}
@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution so here I am all alone answering my own question in case anyone's having the same problem. :)

By adding `crashSound.numberOfLoops = 3;` underneath the crashSound initialization the crashSound will play 3 times.

by adding `crashSound.numberOfLoops = -1;` underneath the crashSound initialization the crashSound will play indefinitely until the `[crashSound stop]` method is called.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html