# Seamless looping Video using AVPlayer- Swift

Tags: ios, video, swift3, avplayer

I am using AVPlayer to play local video in background using loop and video is playing fine but after finishing video it takes pause to play video in loop. I have tried many methods and also seen many post on stack overflow but i failed to find appropriate solution. I am using Swift3.

Code is here :

```
var videoplayer :AVPlayer = AVPlayer()

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "background4", ofType: "mp4")
        videoplayer = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path!))
        videoplayer.volume = 0     
        videoplayer.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEnd.none;

        let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: videoplayer)
        playerLayer.frame = self.view.frame
        playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill

        if (videoplayer.rate != 0) {
            print("playing videoplayer")
            self.blurBgImage.isHidden = true
        }

        playerLayer.zPosition = -1
        videoplayer.rate = 0
        videoplayer.play()
        self.blurBgImage.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)

 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: videoplayer.currentItem, queue: nil, using: { (_) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {

             let t1 = CMTimeMake(5, 100)
            self.videoplayer.seek(to: t1)
            self.videoplayer.play()
        }
    })
}
```

I have also tried AVPlayerLooper. 
Code is :

```
 var playerLooper: NSObject?
var playerLayer:AVPlayerLayer!
var queuePlayer: AVQueuePlayer?

 func playVideo(_ filmName: String){
       if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: filmName, ofType: "mp4")        let url =  URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
         if #available(tvOS 10.0, *) {
          let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url as URL)
            self.videoplayer = AVQueuePlayer(items: [playerItem])
            self.playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: self.videoplayer)
            self.playerLooper = AVPlayerLooper(player: self.videoplayer as! AVQueuePlayer, templateItem: playerItem)
            self.blurBgImage.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer!)
            self.playerLayer?.frame = self.view.frame
            self.videoplayer.volume = 10
            self.videoplayer.play()
        } else {
            videoplayer = AVPlayer(url: url)
            videoplayer.play()
            loopVideo(videoplayer)
        }
}
}
```

What should i do for seamless looping? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361145/looping-a-video-with-avfoundation-avplayer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27808266/how-do-you-loop-avplayer-in-swift

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 Thanks for reply but i did same which you suggest but it is not working.

Comment: Your first block of code is working fine for me make sure you are not doing any other mistake.Its repeating

Comment: It is repeating perfectly but takes a little pause when play in loop. @iOSDev thanks for reply.

Answer (score 4):

FYI there is sample code here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/avloopplayer/Introduction/Intro.html

---

@matt's deleted answer works fine for me (on device / simulator) for iOS 10+ devices:

> Use AVPlayerLooper. That is exactly what it is for.
>
> https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avplayerlooper
>
> Basically it implements AVQueuePlayer for you, constantly updating the
>   queue so that it never ends.

It seamlessly loops without any white/black blip.

E.g.

```
private var looper: AVPlayerLooper?

...

let queuePlayer = AVQueuePlayer(playerItem: item)
looper = AVPlayerLooper(player: queuePlayer, templateItem: item)
videoPlayerLayer.player = queuePlayer
```

If you end up doing this in a reusable cell (e.g. `UICollectionView`), then make sure you disable looping before cell re-use or you'll get some obscure crashes:

```
looper?.disableLooping()
```