# Adding a looped mp4 Background to iOS app signup

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, avplayerlayer

I want to end up applying this code to make my app look a little nicer when users are logging into their social media accounts. I've tried the following code already but my app seems to crash as soon as the mp4 ends.

```
import UIKit

import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

  var avPlayer: AVPlayer!
  var avPlayerLayer: AVPlayerLayer!
  var paused: Bool = false

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let theURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Yeet", withExtension: "mp4")

    avPlayer = AVPlayer(url: theURL!)
    avPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: avPlayer)
    avPlayerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
    avPlayer.volume = 0
    avPlayer.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayer.ActionAtItemEnd.none

    avPlayerLayer.frame = view.layer.bounds
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear;
    view.layer.insertSublayer(avPlayerLayer, at: 0)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: Selector(("playerItemDidReachEnd:")), name:       NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: avPlayer.currentItem)
  }

    @objc func playerItemDidReachEnd(notification: NSNotification) {
    let p: AVPlayerItem = notification.object as! AVPlayerItem
      p.seek(to: CMTime.zero)
  }

  override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
    avPlayer.play()
    paused = false
  }

  override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
    avPlayer.pause()
    paused = true
  }
  override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using [AVPlayerLooper](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayerlooper)?

Looks like @iwasrobbed [has a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42105431/seamless-looping-video-using-avplayer-swift) for iOS 10+ devices. Here's the example code:

```
private var looper: AVPlayerLooper?

...

let queuePlayer = AVQueuePlayer(playerItem: item)
looper = AVPlayerLooper(player: queuePlayer, templateItem: item)
videoPlayerLayer.player = queuePlayer
```

To disable the loop after leaving the view, add this piece of code in the end:

```
looper?.disableLooping()
```

Comment: No problem! Remember to mark the question as answered!