# Remove loop AVPlayer Observer in UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mobile

Hi guys I am having a problem with UIPageViewController and Notifications.

I have a page UIPageVewController with a array of pages, so in these pages I have a AVplayer playing in loop as bellow:

```
 func loopVideo(videoPlayer:AVPlayer){
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: nil, queue: nil){
        [weak videoPlayer] notification in
        videoPlayer?.seek(to: kCMTimeZero)
        videoPlayer?.play()
    }
}
```

The problem is when I change page with scroll the notifications from another pages change my current video playing AVPlayer. I put a print inside the notification and I can see calling the other pages notifications. I don't Know what I have to do?

I tried remove the notification in the viewDidDisappear using NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self) but didn't work.

Can you help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do a check when your notification is received.

Check if the notification object as `AVPlayerItem`  is the same as the visible views player `playerItem`, `videoPlayer.currentItem`

Or simply check if the `AVPlayerItem` in the notification is the same as the `yourCustomView.playerItem`

EDIT:

I see your object is nil, it should be the AVPlayerItem. [Check this thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27808266/how-do-you-loop-avplayer-in-swift)

Comment: Thanks Sneak as do you said I resolved the problem inserting the player.currentItem.

Thanks very much my dear!

Answer (score 11):

`NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)` won't work here as you never added yourself as a target.

Instead keep a reference to your notification and remove it. I think it should look something like this:

```
var notificationObserver:NSObjectProtocol?

func loopVideo(videoPlayer:AVPlayer){
    self.notificationObserver = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: nil, queue: nil){
        [weak videoPlayer] notification in
        videoPlayer?.seek(to: kCMTimeZero)
        videoPlayer?.play()
    }
}

func removeObserver() {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self.notificationObserver)
}
```

Comment: I understood James P thanks for your answer I can understand better now.
I resolved the with the answer from @Sneak.