# ios - Swift 2.2 - SpriteKit - Looping a video with SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, video

When I create a video object with SpriteKit

```
let background = SKVideoNode(videoFileNamed: "Video.mov")
```

I get only one play with the command:

```
background.play()
```

How can I create an infinite loop to make it play all the time ?

I have found some replies about this question, but only in Objective-C, not in Swift. I have to use AVPlayer() but how ?

Thanks for your help,

Comment: You can find [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28814929/play-video-forever-in-sprite-kit) the solution in Objective-C

Comment: Thanks, but how, to convert that in Swift ? I can not add objective-c code into swift files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by compiling different precedent responses from stackoverflow. Here is the working code (swift 2.2). This code loops seamlessly the video playback with a SKSVideoNode object on the scene (with an AVPlayer initializer):

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    let urlStr = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Video_Socle", ofType: "mov")
    let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: urlStr!)

    player = AVPlayer(URL: url)

 NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(AVPlayerItemDidPlayTo     EndTimeNotification
   , object: player!.currentItem, queue: nil)
    { notification in
        let t1 = CMTimeMake(5, 100);
        self.player!.seekToTime(t1)
        self.player!.play()
    }


    videoNode = SKVideoNode(AVPlayer: player!)
    videoNode!.position = CGPointMake(frame.size.width/2, frame.size.height/2)
    videoNode!.size = CGSize(width: 2048, height: 1536)
    videoNode!.zPosition = 0


    background.addChild(videoNode!)
    videoNode!.play()
```