# Play Video in Background of UIViewcontroller-iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, video

I want to play video (.mp4 format) in background continuously(on loop). I tried using the MediaPlayer,AVFoundation but i didn't get the desired result.

I used another method after converting mp4 to gif, .gif worked for me but the quality was low. So please help me find the best method to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what purpose is this? If you're trying to have a video background for a login screen or something of that sort, its better to stick with lower res GIFs. It will save you memory, infact you can get really high quality GIFs from .mp4 files using photoshop but the resolution and frames will eat up iPhone's memory.

Comment: Yes this is behind the login screen, thank you i know your point seems valuable but the problem is project needs a video background, so i need solution for that.

Comment: You can try to use a very high resolution GIF with very less number of frames, this way you will have a high quality video with poor frame rate. You can see here how to do it in photoshop: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v79czy49kTQ  
Using a GIF is anyday a better option over a video file.

Comment: If you're still keen on using video, check this tread: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5365362/5043609
It has your solution.

Comment: Worked perfect but there is a problem i need full screen view and i am getting this currently : http://i62.tinypic.com/bj8t9e.png

Comment: You will have to crop your video before you import it photoshop, crop it to the iPhone's resolution.

Comment: can you give me some idea how that is done. as this is the video i am using:http://www.shutterstock.com/video/clip-3199027-stock-footage-deer-running-in-glenn-afrric-scotland-slow-motion-p-conformed-to-p.html?src=search/xlK0i9Mx4v4qYxLzSQ4uGA:1:6/3p

Comment: You can do it in Final Cut Pro  or any other similar video editing tool.

Answer (score 0):

You can create AVPlayer object in AppDelegate.
Then register its "MovieFinished" observer. In that notification, you can restart the video playing.

Hope this helps.

Comment: But does video play using AVPlayer as it didn work for me using that?