# How can I make my video loop in swift with playerViewController?

Tags: swift, xcode, video, tvos, avplayerviewcontroller

I am trying to loop a video with playerViewController on Swift for TVOS. I have the video playing fine, but I want to loop the video. Here is my code so far:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let videoURL = URL(string: "https://url-to-video.com/video.mp4")
    let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL!)
    let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
    playerViewController.player = player        self.present(playerViewController, animated: true) {
        playerViewController.player!.play()
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: If you're specifically using an **AVPlayerViewController**, https://stackoverflow.com/a/76092161/294884

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The quickest way to do this is to use an AVQueuePlayer with an AVPlayerLooper. You can set the player on your player view controller the same as you would with an ordinary AVPlayer, but you need to keep a persistent reference around to the looper so it’ll keep working. In other words, add this to your view controller’s interface:

```
var looper: AVPlayerLooper?
```

…and in your `viewDidAppear`, replace this:

```
let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL!)
```

with this:

```
let player = AVQueuePlayer()
looper = AVPlayerLooper(player: player, templateItem: AVPlayerItem(asset: AVAsset(url: videoURL!)))
```

Then, once you start the player playing, its video will loop indefinitely.

Comment: Thank you very much. This works perfectly and loops the video smoothly :)

Comment: Also we can use `AVPlayerItem(url:)` instead of `AVPlayerItem(asset:)` here.

Comment: it's very slightly different if specifically using an AVPlayerViewController,  https://stackoverflow.com/a/76092161/294884