# How to reduce iOS AVPlayer start delay

Tags: ios, delay, avplayer

Note, for the below question:  All assets are local on the device -- no network streaming is taking place.  The videos contain audio tracks.

I'm working on an iOS application that requires playing video files with minimum delay to start the video clip in question.  Unfortunately we do not know what specific video clip is next until we actually need to start it up.  Specifically: When one video clip is playing, we will know what the next set of (roughly) 10 video clips are, but we don't know which one exactly, until it comes time to 'immediately' play the next clip.

What I've done to look at actual start delays is to call `addBoundaryTimeObserverForTimes` on the video player, with a time period of one millisecond to see when the video actually started to play, and I take the difference of that time stamp with the first place in the code that indicates which asset to start playing.

From what I've seen thus-far, I have found that using the combination of `AVAsset` loading, and then creating an `AVPlayerItem` from that once it's ready, and then waiting for `AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay` before I call play, tends to take between 1 and 3 seconds to start the clip.

I've since switched to what I think is roughly equivalent: calling `[AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:]` and waiting for `AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay` to play.  Roughly same performance.

One thing I'm observing is that the first AVPlayer item load is slower than the rest.  Seems one idea is to pre-flight the AVPlayer with a short / empty asset before trying to play the first video might be of good general practice. [[Slow start for AVAudioPlayer the first time a sound is played](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/900461/slow-start-for-avaudioplayer-the-first-time-a-sound-is-played])

I'd love to get the video start times down as much as possible, and have some ideas of things to experiment with, but would like some guidance from anyone that might be able to help.

**Update: idea 7, below, as-implemented yields switching times of around 500 ms.  This is an improvement, but it it'd be nice to get this even faster.**

**Idea 1:  Use N AVPlayers (won't work)**

Using ~ 10 `AVPPlayer` objects and start-and-pause all ~ 10 clips, and once we know which one we really need, switch to, and un-pause the correct `AVPlayer`, and start all over again for the next cycle.

I don't think this works, because I've read there is roughly a limit of 4 active `AVPlayer's` in iOS.  There was someone asking about this on StackOverflow here, and found out about the 4 AVPlayer limit: [fast-switching-between-videos-using-avfoundation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7406300/fast-switching-between-videos-using-avfoundation)

**Idea 2: Use AVQueuePlayer (won't work)**

I don't believe that shoving 10 `AVPlayerItems` into an `AVQueuePlayer` would pre-load them all for seamless start.  `AVQueuePlayer` is a queue, and I think it really only makes the next video in the queue ready for immediate playback.  I don't know which one out of ~10 videos we do want to play back, until it's time to start that one. [ios-avplayer-video-preloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354210/ios-avplayer-video-preloading)

**Idea 3: Load, Play, and retain `AVPlayerItems` in background (not 100% sure yet -- but not looking good)**

I'm looking at if there is any benefit to load and play the first second of each video clip in the background (suppress video and audio output), and keep a reference to each `AVPlayerItem`, and when we know which item needs to be played for real, swap that one in, and swap the background AVPlayer with the active one.  Rinse and Repeat.

The theory would be that recently played `AVPlayer/AVPlayerItem`'s may still hold some prepared resources which would make subsequent playback faster.  So far, I have not seen benefits from this, but I might not have the `AVPlayerLayer` setup correctly for the background.  I doubt this will really improve things from what I've seen.

**Idea 4: Use a different file format -- maybe one that is faster to load?**

I'm currently using .m4v's (video-MPEG4) H.264 format.  H.264 has a lot of different codec options, so it's possible that some options are faster to seek than others.  I have found that using more advanced settings that make the file size smaller increase the seek time, but have not found any options that go the other way.

**Idea 5: Combination of lossless video format + AVQueuePlayer**

If there is a video format that is fast to load, but maybe where the file size is insane, one idea might be to pre-prepare the first 10 seconds of each video clip with a version that is bloated but faster to load, but back that up with an asset that is encoded in H.264.  Use an AVQueuePlayer, and add the first 10 seconds in the uncompressed file format, and follow that up with one that is in H.264 which gets up to 10 seconds of prepare/preload time.  So I'd get 'the best' of both worlds:  fast start times, but also benefits from a more compact format.

**Idea 6: Use a non-standard AVPlayer / write my own / use someone else's**

Given my needs, maybe I can't use AVPlayer, but have to resort to AVAssetReader, and decode the first few seconds (possibly write raw file to disk), and when it comes to playback, make use of the raw format to play it back fast.  Seems like a huge project to me, and if I go about it in a naive way, it's unclear / unlikely to even work better.  Each decoded and uncompressed video frame is 2.25 MB.  Naively speaking -- if we go with ~ 30 fps for the video, I'd end up with ~60 MB/s read-from-disk requirement, which is probably impossible / pushing it.  Obviously we'd have to do some level of image compression (perhaps native openGL/es compression formats via PVRTC)... but that's kind crazy.  Maybe there is a library out there that I can use?

**Idea 7: Combine everything into a single movie asset, and seekToTime**

One idea that might be easier than some of the above, is to combine everything into a single movie, and use seekToTime.  The thing is that we'd be jumping all around the place.  Essentially random access into the movie.  I think this may actually work out okay: [avplayer-movie-playing-lag-in-ios5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882621/avplayer-movie-playing-lag-in-ios5)

Which approach do you think would be best?  So far, I've not made that much progress in terms of reducing the lag.

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm going with Idea 7.  It's still slow, but not as unpredictably slow as the other options.  The next question I have is -- do codec options, resolution, and key-frame frequency have an impact on seekto timing?

Comment: Late to the game, but it may be worth switching videos as fast as possible (i.e. immediately after the new one starts to play) and profiling the app to see where it spends most of its CPU time.

Comment: Almost a year later now, what did you ever find out with this?

Comment: I went with option 7, and got to someplace between 300ms and 500ms seeks.  One thing I found is that the fancier the mp4 codec options are the slower the seekTo.  There are some video compression options that allow for better compression and maintain video quality, but kill decoding time.

Comment: Great, thanks for the info.  If you don't mind, could you add an answer which gives the details of your solution and accept it as the "correct" answer so that it gives future people in this situation some guidance?

Comment: That is a reasonable sounding request, but really to implement option 7, there are too many facets in the implementation to post.  Consider:  (a) Make a tool chain to merge video assets, (b) make sure you keep track of video segment offsets, (c) lookup offsets when a request comes in to play a specific clip, (d) use addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval to check if you ran off a video clip and react accordingly (use this method vs. a single-shot addBoundaryTimeObserverForTimes because I have found the latter to sometimes not trigger... overall, this does not lend itself to pasting code.

Comment: Hi, @BerntHabermeier, can you please help me with an issue on AVPlayer? I've been looking for days how to solve it. The problem that I use my internal system to download chunks of mp4 file, each 200k bytes. I use `shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource` protocol to take care about requests. The problem is that when I am trying to perform `seekToTime` on current item, it doesn't requests appropriate byte offset. It just requests all video data from the beginning. Player changes state to `readyToPlay`, but waits untill all data is loaded... Have you ever encountered such problem?

Comment: @kokoko It sounds like you are trying to do video streaming.  Also, it sounds like you are using the `AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate` protocol, of which `shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource` is a method.  I've not used that protocol, so can't help you there, but I think it's a question of what  you are really trying to do.  If you are trying to do video streaming, you should look at: https://developer.apple.com/streaming/.  If you are just trying to download a big file in small chunks, you can do that entirely without `AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate`.

Answer (score 9):

For iOS 10.x and greater to reduce AVPlayer start delay I set: 
`avplayer.automaticallyWaitsToMinimizeStalling = false;`
 and that seemed to fix it for me. This could have other consequences, but I haven't hit those yet.

I got the idea for it from:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50598525/9620547

Comment: I got 6-7 seconds of reduction in delay. But I have a question here, will it impact on app performance?

Comment: @kalpa We've used this code in a production app for over a year without any discernible negative effects.  We mostly play 20-60 minute audio files to listeners in the US where mobile data coverage is generally fast.  Your use case could be different though.

Answer (score 1):

The asset may not ready once you create it, it may does calculations like duration of movie, be sure to contain all metadata of the movie in the file.

Answer (score 1):

You should try option #7 first, just to see if you can get that working. I suspect that it will not actually work for your needs since the seek time will likely not be fast enough to give you seamless switching between clips. If you try that and it fails, then I would advise that you do option 4/6 and take a look at my iOS library designed specifically for this purpose, just do a quick google search on AVAnimator to find out more. My library makes it possible to implement seamless loops and switching from one clip to another, it is very fast because video has to be decoded into a file before hand. In your case, all 10 video clips would get decoded into files before you begin, but then switching between them would be fast.

Comment: What about the audio portion of the video?  I need video and audio to be synchronized.

Comment: Yes, audio is already handled with very tight sync between the audio track and the video clip. See the example xcode projects. It is already all implemented, you just need to download and try it out.

Comment: Is there a possibility to play network video using AVAnimator?

Comment: No, it works on local files, streaming network video is a completely different thing.

Answer (score 0):

Without having done anything like this in the past, based on your thoughts and experiences I would try a combination of 7 and 1: Preload one AVPlayer with the first couple of seconds of the 10 follow up videos. Then skipping will very likely be faster and more reliable due to less data. While you are playing the selected piece, you have enough time to prepare the AVPlayer for the rest of the selected follow up video in the background. When the beginning is finished, you switch to the prepared AVPlayer. So in total, you at any given time have a maximum of 2 AVPlayers loaded.

Of course I don't know whether the switching can be done so smoothly that it does not disturb playback.

(Would have added this as a comment if I could.)

Best, Peter

Comment: I have found no benefit of loading 10 assets in series on one AVPlayer.  Further, I don't understand your suggestion, as I see option (1) and (7) mutually exclusive.  Option 7 merges all video assets into a single asset -- thus there is only a single asset to load period.  This is what I'm doing today, and for what it's worth I'm getting roughly a 500 ms delay on actual start/play times.  It's  worth noting that the SeekTo completes faster than the actual first frame is played, so for true start-times, I measure when the first frame is actually playing back via timed callback.

Comment: Just to make my idea clear: My idea was to split an asset into two parts: the first few seconds and the rest. Now you have made two assets out of one. The 10 beginnings you'd join and use skip and while playing the beginning you'd load the rest. This then comprises suggestion 8 which adds to your list.

Comment: But as I understand from your last comment, meanwhile you pushed research further which is good, and solution 7 does not work out either. It looks as if AV fundamentally stays in your way and the only way for you to go probably is to use the technology underneath, that is Core Media, to get more control over your assets. Peter.

Comment: Oh, I understand your idea better now.  Thanks.  It would be interesting to investigate if you get fast seek-times for short video clips.  I have not tried that yet, but would be worth a consideration.  Regarding the use of core media -- I have not found any good reference material on that API.  Do you have a good resource you can point me at?

Comment: Nope, sorry. As I said, I'm not an expert on either AV or Core Media. Just read your Question and had some ideas how I personally would proceed and wanted to share them. Peter

Comment: Probably worth baring in mind that loading large media files, or many at once, will have an impact on your memory that you'll have to watch out for as that may slow things down also.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your issue correctly, it seems that you have one continuous video to which you need to load the audio track for on a moment's notice.

If that is the case I suggest looking into [BASS](http://un4seen.com). BASS is an audio library much like AVPlayer that gives you (relatively) easy access to the low-level API's of the AudioUnits framework in iOS. What does the mean for you? It means that with a tiny bit of buffer manipulation (you may not even need it, depends on how tiny you want the delay) you can start playing music instantly.

The limitations however extend to video, as I said, it is an **audio** library so any video manipulation will still have to be done with AVPlayer. However using`-seekToTime:toleranfeBefore:toleranceAfter:` you should be able to achieve fast seeking within the video as long as you preroll with all the necessary options.

If you're syncing across multiple devices (which your application might suggest) just leave a comment and I'd be happy to edit my answer.

PS: BASS may look daunting at first because of it's C-like format, but it's really really easy to use for what it is.

Answer (score -2):

Here are several properties and methods provided by the AVAsset class that may help:

```
- (void)_pu_setCachedDuration:(id)arg1;
- (id)pu_cachedDuration; 
- (struct
 { 
   long long x1; 
   int x2;
   unsigned int x3; 
   long long x4; 
})pu_duration;
- (void)pu_loadDurationWithCompletionHandler:(id /* block */)arg1;
```