# Looping playback from server not working as expected with AVFoundation AVPlayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, avplayer

When playing an .mp4 locally from device the media loops the playback as expected.  When the media is from a server no notification is fired when the video stops playing

```
AVPlayer *avPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.someurl.com/someMedia.mp4"]];
AVPlayerLayer *avPlayerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:avPlayer];
avPlayerLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
[self.view.layer addSublayer:avPlayerLayer];

[avPlayer play];


// Loop video
avPlayer.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:)
                                             name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                           object:[avPlayer currentItem]];




- (void)playerItemDidReachEnd:(NSNotification *)notification {

    NSLog(@"Video ended");

    AVPlayerItem *p = [notification object];
    [p seekToTime:kCMTimeZero];
}
```

Checked [Looping a video with AVFoundation AVPlayer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361145/looping-a-video-with-avfoundation-avplayer/26401680#26401680) and [How do I loop a video with AVFoundation without unwanted pauses at the end?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13428831/how-do-i-loop-a-video-with-avfoundation-without-unwanted-pauses-at-the-end)

**UPDATE**

Thanks to ChrisH for this, creating a delay to allow for the video to be loaded from the server before observing player lops the video correctly

```
double delayInSeconds = 7.0;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){

        avPlayer.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:)
                                                     name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                                   object:[avPlayer currentItem]];



    });
```

Comment: Is `currentItem` set on your `avPlayer` object when you add the observer? It's probably taking a little longer to load the item from a remote URL.

Comment: Not sure what you mean `currentItem` set on your `avPlayer` , everything in the pasted code is "as is".  The looping file is four seconds  loading time  time is near instant, plus the `NSNotification is never called `

Comment: You are instantiating `AVPlayer` with an `NSURL` and then immediately observing notifications from that instance's `currentItem` which may still be nil. The `currentItem` will not be set until `avPlayer` has loaded the content from the server.

Comment: Ah ok now it makes sense and is totally correct, can you make that an answer and I shall mark it as correct.  Many thanks for that

Comment: No worries - answered!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that the notification is not firing for a remote mp4 is that you are observing notifications from the `AVPlayer` instance's `currentItem` immediately after the player is created, and the `currentItem` will be `nil` until the content has been loaded from the server.

The recommended way to handle this is to observe the `status` property of the player instance, and once that status equals `AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay` you can start observing notifications from the `currentItem`. There's a good explanation along with sample code in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5403162/228981)