# How does Vine looping video playback work on iOS?

Tags: ios, video, avfoundation, vine

Vine loops videos without any pauses in between loops. I've tried creating an `AVPlayer` that plays the video from the beginning whenever it ends. This introduces a slight lag between every loop. I'm looking for suggestions of ways to avoid this lag.

I have considered creating much longer videos out of repeating short clips. Am I missing some obvious solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AVPlayerQueue to queue up the videos (in this case the same one multiple times), and it will handle playing them in sequence.

For example

[iPhone Smooth Transition from One Video To Another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410003/iphone-smooth-transition-from-one-video-to-another/17138580#17138580)