# How to add alpha channel video as overlay?

Tags: ios, video, overlay, editing

I am doing a video editing app. In this I need to add video overlay on another video. I am able to add video overlay by decreasing opacity. but when I am trying to add alpha channel videos(for transparency) its showing black background instead of transparent . I need transparent video for showing rain , thunder effect.
Can anyone suggest how to add transparent videos.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be done but not with the built-in tools provided with iOS. See [iPhone Smooth Transition from One Video To Another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410003/iphone-smooth-transition-from-one-video-to-another/17138580#17138580)